processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED
When I was building a debug from Flutter, with the just_audio package, I encountered a few similar errors stated in the title.  Build output said:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library

Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.fragment" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Related packages include just_audio and purchases_ui_flutter, and some of their dependencies. i.e. audio_session, SQLite
I have already defined minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle file:
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "xxx.xxxx.xxxx"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.

        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
    }

But I am still seeing the minSdk error prompt.  Sorry that I am a newbie and maybe I'm asking a dumb question. I spent a few days figuring out what happened and even started a new project, but the issue persisted.
Here is what I tried:
Updated flutter dependencies with
flutter clean
flutter pub get

updated Android Studio.
Clean and Rebuild the project via Android Studio
add minSdkVersion 24 and targetSdkVersion 34 lines as described above.
